# Is list different implementation a polymorphism?

Tags: java, list, polymorphism

```
List <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 

List <String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Two these objects gives List, but the implementation is different. 
Is it calling a polymorphism?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called [subtype polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping).

It is one of the several types of the general concept of "polymorphism."

Comment: Thank you :)
I thought so, but I wasn't sure.